# How can I load my emacs configuration when I'm in -nw mode (opening emacs in terminal)

Tags: linux, emacs, configuration, terminal

Well like the question says, my problem refers when I start emacs on terminal (in Linux).

My packages appears but my configuration (init.el file) it's not loaded.
My keybindings are not working, and yes, I searched about and only I can think is that I need have other specific file for run in terminal.

Any help?

Comment: The default Emacs initialization file is `.emacs`, not `init.el`. `-nw` has no effect on whether the `.emacs` is loaded. Maybe there's code in your `.emacs` that checks whether it's running in a window or not.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar but this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init) says that you can have some config files.

Comment: OK, sorry about that. But my point still stands, maybe you have code in your `init.el` that does `(if window-system ...)`

Comment: @Barmar Yeah maybe. I'm gonna need to check that..

Comment: emacs.stackexchange.com is probably a better place to ask questions about using Emacs.

Comment: Emacs reads the same config file regardless of whether it is run in gui or text mode. Check your *Messages* buffer. Note also that 'terminal' means different things. For example, if your running emacs -nw in the Linux console (i.e. no X), then some key bindings don't work because the console doesn't accept the same key combinations as X (or an X based terminal emulator like xterm). You can put a (message "Reading init") in your .emacs or emacs.d/init.el

Comment: Also make sure you don't run emacs with `-Q` for some reason which prevents it from reading the config to start quicker.